# ADD sql table structure to a EXISTED table

Tags: mysql

i know`CREATE TABLE new LIKE old;`,but it can't copy fields to a existing table
i want to add the field,type and collation to an existing table
is there any simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to `SHOW CREATE TABLE old` then copy & paste the columns you want to add to your existing table, and use them in an `ALTER TABLE` statement . You can use `ADD COLUMN` to add multiple columns in one statement.

There's no shortcut syntax for this. It's unlikely that you would want to copy *all* the columns. For example, you can't copy columns that conflict with column names in the existing table.

There are edge cases, like what if a column has `NOT NULL` but no `DEFAULT`? You can't add that to an existing table unless the table is empty.

You just have to build the `ALTER TABLE` statement to suit what you want to do. This is similar to most other custom programming scenarios.